# How to hide content on server for crawlers and hackers

Tags: apache, security, server, robots.txt

I'm selling e-books in my online shop. When a buyer has finished he gets an e-mail with the download link like this:

```
http://www.my_domain.com/media/books/b476de3dd02e72a727bb762371d6bbad.pdf
```

Every file has a cryptic name like `b476de3dd02e72a727bb762371d6bbad` to prevent a user could guess the name, and not `my_book_name.pdf`.

In `robots.txt` I have the following to prevent crawlers to crawl it and show it in the search results:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /media/books/
```

I know that a crawler *can* note it but *mustn't*.

Does anybody know a better solution? What's the common way to do that?

*P.S. I don't want to force the user to input a password or so to access the file.*

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your website has a major access control issue. What if one user buys an ebook and then shares the link on social media?

You need to make sure that the user downloading the file is actually the one that paid for it. In other words, you need authentication. Files should not be referenced directly on the server, because that way you cannot implement authorization.

While I think it's fairly common to log in with a username/password to a webshop to download any digital goods you purchased. However, I understand you don't want to do that, but you still have to authenticate your user.

One thing you could do is when somebody purchases something, you could create a cryptographically random token (ie. a large random string) and store it in your database, linked to the file that can be downloaded with the token, and also the user if there are users. There should be a timestamp too to limit the time available for the token to be used.

Then you could have an endpoint, something like `/media/books/download/<<token>>` for the user to get the file (or `/media/books/download/<<token>>/<<filename>>` to allow multiple files with the same token). The point is, it would be different for each user that purchased the same book, and it would also be time-limited. You could limit the number of allowed downloads, or have monitoring in place to detect if a token is used from many multiple client IP addresses, etc. to try and discover fraud. It will not be perfect, but maybe you can deter most attackers unless you are selling very special books. :) But if you don't do all this, it would still be much better than a direct link to the file.

This would also inherently solve the search engine problem.

Answer (score 0):

One better option option is to use the following in .htaccess file placed inside directory of these files that you are talking about.

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
```

The robots.txt file only contains the so called Crawler directives, telling search engines, identified by their User-agent:, where they are not allowed to go by using Disallow: and where they can (and should) go by using Allow:, and by pointing them at a Sitemap:.

Comment: Thank for your answer. What exactly does it?